# Not getting 0 value in SQL count aggregate by inner join

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, count, left-join

I am using the basic chinook database and I am trying to get a query that will display the worst selling genres. I am mostly getting the answer, however there is one genre 'Opera' that has 0 sales, but the query result is ignoring that and moving on to the next lowest non-zero value.

I tried using left join instead of inner join but that returns different values.

This is my query currently:

```
create view max 
as 
    select distinct 
        t1.name as genre,
        count(*) as Sales 
    from 
        tracks t2 
    inner join 
        invoice_items t3 on t2.trackid == t3.trackid 
    left join 
        genres as t1 on t1.genreid == t2.genreid 
    group by 
        t1.genreid 
    order by 
        2 
    limit 10;
```

The result however skips past the opera value which is 0 sales. How can I include that? I tried using left join but it yields different results.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Comment: Your GROUP BY is invalid and expected to raise an error. (However, sqlite might to things in its own way...) You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions. I.e. I'd try GROUP BY t1.name.

Comment: t2, t3 and t1 are poor table aliases. Chose something that makes sense, like `g` for `genres`.

Comment: @jarlh: You are mistaken. The `GROUP BY` clause is valid. With `genreid` being the table's primary key, `name` is functional dependent on this column and can hence be used in the select clause. I know there are DBMS out there that are not capable of detecting functional dependency and simply forbid such cases in order not to have to deal with this, but this makes them non standard compliant in this regard.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, this is why t1 is such a poor table alias... I didn't even consider t1.genreid being the primary key. (And id is a much more common primary key column name.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to include genres with no sales then you should start the joins from `genres` and then do `LEFT` joins to the other tables.
Also, you should not use `count(*)` which counts any row in the resultset.

```
SELECT g.name Genre, 
       COUNT(i.trackid) Sales 
FROM genres g 
LEFT JOIN tracks t ON t.genreid = g.genreid 
LEFT JOIN invoice_items i ON i.trackid = t.trackid 
GROUP BY g.genreid
ORDER BY Sales LIMIT 10;
```

There is no need for the keyword `DISTINCT`, since the query returns 1 row for each genre.

Comment: Thanks, this works! I understand the point about the left join now.

Answer (score 1):

When asking for the top n one must always state how to deal with ties. If I am looking for the top 1, but there are three rows in the table, all with the same value, shall I select 3 rows? Zero rows? One row arbitrarily chosen? Most often we don't want arbitrary results, which excludes the last option. This excludes `LIMIT`, too, because `LIMIT` has no clause for ties in SQLite.

Here is an example with `DENSE_RANK` instead. You are looking for the worst selling genres, so we must probably look at the revenue per genre, which is the sum of price x quantity sold. In order to include genres without invoices (and maybe even without tracks?) we outer join this data to the genre table.

```
select total, genre_name
from
(
  select
    g.name as genre_name,
    coalesce(sum(ii.unit_price * ii.quantity), 0) as total
    dense_rank() over (order by coalesce(sum(ii.unit_price * ii.quantity), 0)) as rnk
  from genres g
  left join tracks t on t.genreid = g.genreid
  left join invoice_items ii on ii.trackid = t.trackid
  group by g.name
) aggregated
where rnk <= 10
order by total, genre_name;
```